# How can I classify the contents in 2 groups based on their values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a relational schema as follows:

```
INVENTORY(inventoryID,title,wholesale,markup,qtyinStock,discount)
Primary-Key: inventoryID

BOOK(coverType,inventoryID)
Primary-Key: inventoryID
Foreign-Key: inventoryID

DVD(classification,ReleaseYear,StarRating)
Primary-Key: inventoryID
Foreign-Key: inventoryID
```

BOOK and DVD are basically the subtypes of Inventory. They are inheriting from INVENTORY. Now, I want to display all the items in the inventory as either a book or a DVD depending upon the items presence in the table. I did the following but I am not sure if this is right:

```
SELECT title FROM INVENTORY,BOOK,DVD
WHERE INVENTORY.inventoryID = BOOK.inventoryID AND INVENTORY.inventoryID = DVD.inventoryID
```

This doesn't display the titles of the items though. How can I add that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I read your question incorrectly the query is simple. Your example query pulls inventory that is both a DVD and Book.

```
SELECT title,
CASE WHEN b.inventoryID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Book'
  WHEN d.inventoryID IS NOT NULL THEN 'DVD'
END AS Category
FROM Inventory i
JOIN Book b on i.inventoryID = b.inventoryID
JOIN DVD d on d.inventoryID  = i.InventoryID
```

Comment: ,So, I want to display whether an item in the inventory is a book or a DVD. I think your query just displays the title. That's it. I want to display the category as well (DVD/Book).

Comment: @HarryLewis I updated the answer. I only pulled the title because that is what you were pulling in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

With the `AND` in the WHERE clause you are trying to get the title of the inventory item that is both book AND dvd. Try changing the `AND` for and `OR`

Comment: So, I want to display whether an item in the inventory is a book or a DVD. I think your suggestion just displays the title. That's it. I want to display the category as well (DVD/Book).